# Xamarin - clearing ListView selection

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms

I am actually working with this piece of code

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CryptoUI
{
    public class HomePage : Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
        // Set up the Master, i.e. the Menu
            Label header = new Label
            {
                Text = "MENU",
                Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(20, FontAttributes.Bold),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
        // create an array of the Page names
        string[] myPageNames = {
            "Main",
            "Page 2",
            "Page 3",
        };

        // Create ListView for the Master page.
        ListView listView = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = myPageNames,
        };

        // The Master page is actually the Menu page for us
        this.Master = new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "Test",
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = 
                {
                    header, 
                    listView
                },
            }
        };

        // Define a selected handler for the ListView contained in the Master (ie Menu) Page.
        listView.ItemSelected += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Set the BindingContext of the detail page.
            this.Detail.BindingContext = args.SelectedItem;

            string currentPage = this.GetType().Name.ToString();

            // This is where you would put your “go to one of the selected pages”
            if(listView.SelectedItem.Equals("Main") && !currentPage.Equals("HomePage")){
                AsyncPush(new HomePage());
            }
            else if(listView.SelectedItem.Equals("Page 2") && !currentPage.Equals("SecondPage")){
                AsyncPush(new SecondPage());
            }
            else if(listView.SelectedItem.Equals("Page 3") && !currentPage.Equals("ThirdPage")){
                AsyncPush(new ThirdPage());
            }               

            // Show the detail page.
            this.IsPresented = false;
        };
            listView.ItemSelected += (senders, e) => {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null) return; // don't do anything if we just de-selected the row
                // do something with e.SelectedItem
                ((ListView)senders).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
            };

        // Set up the Detail, i.e the Home or Main page.
        Label myHomeHeader = new Label
        {
            Text = "Home Page",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        string[] homePageItems = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" };
        ListView myHomeView = new ListView {
            ItemsSource = homePageItems,
        };

        var myHomePage = new ContentPage();

        myHomePage.Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = 
            {
                myHomeHeader, 
                myHomeView
            } ,
        };
        this.Detail = myHomePage;
    }

        public async void AsyncPush(Page page)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        }
    }
}
```

This code actually shows an easy FlyOut menu, using the Xamarin Forms technologies.
I am currently trying to understand how I could easily clear the ListView selection after I have selected which page I want to head to!

I found this piece of code on Xamarin's website for devs (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/);

```
listView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.SelectedItem == null) return; // don't do anything if we just de-selected the row
    // do something with e.SelectedItem
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
};
```

But I can't currently figure out how I should integrate it with my code above there :)

Comment: First you will not need to separate ItemSelected events to do this. I think you can just call this `listview.SelectedItem = null` to reset the listview selecteditem property. Either before or after you push the new page. Second, it might be better to use `ItemTapped` to start the page transition and use itemselected to process/pass the data to next view.

Comment: your code: public async void AsyncPush(Page page)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        }
introduces a bug that allows users to double tap links and open multiple pages to the nav stack.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're assigning the ItemSelected handler twice, which is a bad idea.  All you should have to do is add this line to your existing ItemSelected handler

```
  ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! Anyway I already tried that earlier, all I am getting is this: http://1drv.ms/1s0K0cO as soon as I click on any element in the ListView

Comment: If you add that line to the top of your ItemSelected handler, then all the subsequent references to SelectedItem will break because it is now null.  Try adding it at the bottom of the handler, after all the other code referencing it is done.

Comment: Well, if you look at the screenshot I linked there, I am doing what you are saying, still everything is crashing :(

Comment: Try checking for SelectedItem != null before you enter that big IF block.

Answer (score 21):

I would like to add to Jason's answer because it misses some vital information.  When you set the ListView SelectedItem property to null, it will fire off the ItemSelected event again.  So if you do not have a null check, it will throw an exception.

This is what it should look like:

```
void ItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (((ListView)sender).SelectedItem == null)
      return;
    //Do stuff here with the SelectedItem ...
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer thanks man, here's a gist confirming your idea https://gist.github.com/ajonno/6ae0d2aebfae79d2ec9c

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem but the other solutions did not work for me. Since I needed to pass a custom object to the next page I nullified the selected item reference and used the item tapped reference for my custom object.

```
listView.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) =>{

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(e.Item as CustomObject));
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

};
```

Comment: Since you're async on the navigation you introduce a bug that allows users to push two items to the nav stack if they double click fast enough.  You'll have to hit the back button twice to clear both pages.

Answer (score 2):

**ListView.SelectedItem** does not have setter (I mean simple Xamarin Android - not Xamarin.Forms). I suggest to use the following code:

```
private void DeselectEntities()
{
    if (this.listView != null && this.listView.CheckedItemPositions != null)
    {
        this.listView.CheckedItemPositions.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I respect all given answers but in an MVVM app you'd better avoid too much code behind. What I usually do is following:

1. Bind ItemsSource of ListView as usual to an ObservableCollection where T is a CarViewModel in my case
2. Set **SelectionMode="None"**: This does avoid the selection of SelectedItem on tap
3. Use EventToCommandBehavior (I use my own implementation; see github.com or use the one from Prism.Forms) to bind ItemTapped event of ListView to my ViewModel command SelectedCarChangedCommand.
4. In the ViewModel's SelectedCarChangedCommand you'll receive the tabbed item as ItemTappedEventArgs object.

   ```
    <ListView
      x:Name="CarsListView"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
      SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
                Command="{Binding SelectedCarChangedCommand}"
                EventName="ItemTapped" />
        </ListView.Behaviors>
   ```

Comment: Normally this is good but I've found that in the case of pushing the navigation stack that commands are not effective because you can double-triple-10 tap and open many instances.

Comment: True. You can handle such multi-touch cases by setting the canExecute flag in your SelectedCarChangedCommand implementation. I think thats how I solved it.