# Selected ListviewItem remains selected in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have the following XAML code:

```
  <ListView x:Name="listView"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                                             Padding="20,5,20,5">
                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">

                                        <Label FontSize="Medium"
                                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                               Text="{Binding Name}"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Start" />

                                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">

                                            <Label FontSize="Small"
                                                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                                   Text="{Binding Info1}"
                                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Start" />
                                            <Label FontSize="Small"
                                                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                                   Text="{Binding Info2}"
                                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Start" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>

                                    <Image HorizontalOptions="End"
                                           IsVisible="{Binding IsDone}"
                                           Source="Image1.png" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>

                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Command="{Binding DeleteEntryCommand, Source={x:Reference listView}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                          IsDestructive="true"
                                          Text="Delete" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

When I click an item, it navigates to a new *Page*.

```
public Data SelectedData
    {
      get { return selectedData; }
      set
      {
        selectedData= value;
        if(value!=null)
           navigationService.For<InfoViewModel>().Navigate();
        selectedData=null;
      }
    }
```

When I navigate back, ***the item is still selected***, so I can't select it again.

What should I do to make it "release" the item?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to `null` => `SelectedData = null` ?

Comment: @Nudity I modified the initial post. I can set it to null, but it does not work.

Comment: you could try this .. otherwise I have no idea .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7089457/4610605

Comment: btw are you using `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?

Comment: @Nudity Yes, I do, but it is woven with an AOP library.

Comment: also this may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306685/xamarin-clearing-listview-selection

Comment: as far as I could find any information setting it to `null` should work.. I guess the null value is applied to the property but your view is not updating.. just for trial what if you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call `OnPropertyChanged()` is it working then ?

Comment: I tried to call `OnPropertyChanged` but it didn't work, so I ended up using the suggested event solution. If you promote your comment, I'll accept it.